# Potential Difference across two cells in series

Tags: electricity, potential, batteries

I studied yesterday that total potential difference across two cells in series is simply the algebraic sum of potential difference of those two cells. And by which logic it has been proved, I am unable to grasp it.
Or When I used the same logic to calculate the total V, it didn't work.
Let's say I have two cells P and Q. The +ve terminal of P is at +10 and -ve terminal at -10. Similarly +ve terminal of Q is at +5 and negative at -5 as shown in figure.
[image]

So, there are four points viz A,B,C and D. A being close to +ve terminal of P should be at +10, B being close to -ve terminal should be at -10. Similarly C and D would have potential +5 and -5 respectively.

[image]

Now, I wish to calculate potential difference between point A and D. So I can write:

V<sub>AD</sub> = V<sub>A</sub>-V<sub>D</sub> = (V<sub>A</sub>-V<sub>B</sub>) + (V<sub>B</sub>-V<sub>C</sub>) + (V<sub>C</sub> - V<sub>D</sub>)
V<sub>AD</sub> = V<sub>A</sub> -V<sub>D</sub> = (10-(-10)) + (-10-5) + (5-(-5))
V<sub>AD</sub> = V<sub>A</sub> -V<sub>D</sub> = 20 + (-15) + 10
V<sub>AD</sub> = V<sub>A</sub> -V<sub>D</sub> = 15

But, the answer ideally should be 30 (if we simply add the potential difference of two cells which are 20 and 10 respectively.)
So, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the potentials, $V_A,\ V_B,\ V_C,\ V_D$ are with respect to some third body such as the Earth.

$(V_B-V_C)$ may be non-zero before the cells are connected together, but within a very small fraction of a second, charge will have flowed through the wire BC, equalising the potentials of B and C, so $V_{BC}=0$ and no more charge flows through BC.

When dealing with cells in circuits we don't usually concern ourselves with small transient flows of charge like these, and we don't give the battery terminals individual potentials with respect to a 'third' object, because these potentials don't survive. All we specify are the potential *differences* between the terminals of the cells, because these are characteristic of the (unloaded) cells themselves.

So, in your case, $\    V_{AD} =V_{AB}+V_{BC}+V_{CD}=\ $20 V + 0 + 10 V = 30V.